# how to display weekly attendance in rails for the selected month?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, weak-references, monthcalendar

iam having two dropdowns month dropdown and year dropdown. and submit button.i want to display the attendance for the selected month and selected year in dropdown. firstly when a month is selected i want to show  only the attendance for the first weak of the selected month in month dropdown.and i want to have to buttons left arrow and right arrow to see the attendance for the next weak and for the previous .  i want to have a tabular form which shows weak dates as columns in view.and i want to display attendance for that day in the corresponding columns.how can i implement this in rails? is there any plugin?

```
<- Previous Week  Next Week -> 
Child   | Monday 5/6 | Tuesday 5/7 | Wednesday 5/8 | Thursday 5/9 so on... 
child1  | __________ | ___________ | _____________ | ____________ | 
child2  | __________ | ___________ | _____________ | ____________ | 
Submit
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/), more specifically its "basic week" view (view all views [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/)). Fullcalendar has a rails-specific gem which you can find [here](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails).